# Interpolate line to make a half-circle/arc in d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a half circle in d3. Using [cardinal interpolation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate) produces a path that is close to what I want, but isn't quite "circular" enough. How can I write my own interpolator to better round this path, or is there a better method?

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/jEfsh/

```
<svg width="300" height="500">
    <g id="g-1"></g>
    <g id="g-2"></g>
</svg>​
```

JS:

```
var curved = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .tension(0);
var straight = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .interpolate("linear")
    .tension(0);

var points = [{x: 70, y: 52.5}, {x: 250, y: 250}, {x: 70, y: 447.5}];

d3.select("#g-1").append("path").attr("d", curved(points));

d3.select("#g-2").append("path").attr("d", straight(points));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See: [How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle)

---

The problem with using d3.arc() to create curved lines is that it layers two lines on top of each other. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595157/522877

[`d3.svg.line.radial()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_radial) has significantly more control when it comes to creating arcs and circles.

Here is an example of how to create a circle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/CrDUy/

```
var radius = 100,
    padding = 10,
    radians = 2 * Math.PI;

var dimension = (2 * radius) + (2 * padding),
    points = 50;

var angle = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, points-1])
    .range([0, radians]);

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .tension(0)
    .radius(radius)
    .angle(function(d, i) { return angle(i); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", dimension)
    .attr("height", dimension)
.append("g");

svg.append("path").datum(d3.range(points))
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (radius + padding) + ", " + (radius + padding) + ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [arc section](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-arc)?

Comment: That ended up being what I decided to use for this. I think I'd still like to know how I would go about doing this with a custom interpolator, if possible.

Comment: The problem with using d3.arc() to create curved lines is that it layers two lines on top of each other. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11595157/522877

Comment: Makes sense. Like the example and what you did with `stroke-dasharray`