# SVG JavaScript "pie wedge" generator

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create a "pie wedge". And I'm bad at it. It's been a LONG time since I took trig. I have looked at lots of examples, and have this code generator worked out in JS:

```
var startPointX = 200;
var startPointY = 200;
var startAngle = 180;
var endAngle = 210;
var x1 = startPointX + 180*Math.cos(Math.PI*startAngle/180); 
var y1 = startPointY + 180*Math.sin(Math.PI*startAngle/180); 

var x2 = startPointX + 180*Math.cos(Math.PI*endAngle/180);
var y2 = startPointY + 180*Math.sin(Math.PI*endAngle/180);
console.log("M200,200 L" + x1 + "," + y1 + " A180,180 0 0,1 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " z");
```

It works great!

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <path d="M200,200 L20,200 A180,180 0 0,1 44.1,110 z" fill="red" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" />
</svg>
```

But, what I need to do is **change the radius of the "wedge" that's generated**. I can't seem to figure out which parameters correspond, or how I would go about modifying my equations to compensate. Replacing all the "180"s gives me some freaky results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first two values in the arc (after the A) are the starting coordinates of the arc, so should equal x1, y1. Try:

```
var startPointX = 200;
var startPointY = 200;
var startAngle = 180;
var endAngle = 210;
var radius = 100;

var x1 = startPointX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * startAngle/180); 
var y1 = startPointY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * startAngle/180);     
var x2 = startPointX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * endAngle/180);
var y2 = startPointY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * endAngle/180);

console.log("M200,200 L" + x1 + "," + y1 + " A" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0,1 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " z");
```

Comment: I believe the first two numbers after the A are the x-radius and y-radius, not coordinates.

Comment: @BrandonBrooks You're correct, thanks. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 7):

I used a modified version of the accepted answer, because the wedge was deforming with  different sizes. I just changed the size of the circle the arc is drawn by to the circle's radius. This works for wedges less than 180 degrees.

```
var generateWedgeString = function(startX, startY, startAngle, endAngle, radius){
        var x1 = startX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * startAngle/180);
        var y1 = startY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * startAngle/180);
        var x2 = startX + radius * Math.cos(Math.PI * endAngle/180);
        var y2 = startY + radius * Math.sin(Math.PI * endAngle/180);

        var pathString = "M"+ startX + " " + startY + " L" + x1 + " " + y1 + " A" + radius + " " + radius + " 0 0 1 " + x2 + " " + y2 + " z";

        return pathString;

    }
```

Comment: You can also easily add support for wedges more than 180 by adding:
`var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";`

And replacing `" 0 0 1 "` with `" 0 " + largeArcFlag +" 1 "`

Answer (score 1):

Don't replace ALL the 180s, just the ones that don't involve converting between degrees and radians. So the 4 occurrences inside the trig functions (`Math.cos(...)`, `Math.sin(...)`), should be left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Who wants this in PHP?  YOU DO!  I've modified No Context's answer and mixed with opsb's answer from [How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle):

```
function polarToCartesian($centerX, $centerY, $radius, $angleInDegrees) {
    $angleInRadians = ($angleInDegrees - 90) * pi() / 180.0;
    return array(
        "x" => $centerX + ($radius * cos($angleInRadians)),
        "y" => $centerY + ($radius * sin($angleInRadians)),
    );
}

function describeArc($x, $y, $radius, $startAngle, $endAngle){
    $start = polarToCartesian($x, $y, $radius, $startAngle);
    $end = polarToCartesian($x, $y, $radius, $endAngle);
    $arcSweep = $endAngle - $startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

    return "M $x $y L $start[x] $start[y] A $radius $radius 0 $arcSweep 1 $end[x] $end[y] z";
}
```

Note, that if you want a wedge that goes to 360, use 359.9999.