# How to draw circle animation not using canvas?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I have a background image, and a div child in which I draw a circle. Here some sample code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hybAs .

I want to be able to "erase" this circle like [image: pacman]
<sub>(source: [openprocessing.org](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/thumbnail/49858/cache/2012-03-04%2019:48:05))</sub>
Pacman until there is no more draw, so image will appear . While increasing the clean sector angle  it would be showing image bellow it. I want this to be an animation , no problem if it is html, jquery or css, but I can't not use canvas. Please ask me anything if my question isn't clear enough.

Comment: So, without using canvas, your options are: SVG, or using several triangles.

Comment: You should check [this example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/animated-pac-man-in-pure-css3).

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the svg path to create an arc. I found the arc creating sample here:
[How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle)

Now just iterate from 0 to 360 degree angle to create the arc using setInterval as below:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1300" width="1600" viewBox="0 0 1600 1300" id="star-svg">
<path id="arc1" fill="none" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="50" />
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = document.getElementById("arc1");
var i =1;
var int = setInterval(function() {  
    if (i>360) { clearInterval(int); return;};
    a.setAttribute("d", describeArc(200, 200, 25, 0, i));
    i++;
}, 10);

function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

    var arcSweep = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

    var d = [
        "M", start.x, start.y, 
        "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
    ].join(" ");

    return d;       
}
</script>
```