# Drawing parts of circle's circumference in SVG

Tags: svg, path, geometry

I need to draw in SVG parts of circle's circumference in different colours (please look at the picture below). Unfortunately I'm not good at SVG, so I found solution which is in my opinion very poor: I'm using `describeArc()` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle/24569190#24569190) and I draw two paths - one colourful circle and, over it, white circle with smaller radius. For example:

```
PATH1 = describeArc(x=10000, y=5000, radius=3000, startAngle=45, endAngle=90)
PATH2 = describeArc(x=10000, y=5000, radius=2800, startAngle=45, endAngle=90)
```

and after inserting it into svg, I have:

```
 <path d=PATH1 fill="red" stroke-width="0" />
 <path d=PATH2 fill="white" stroke="white" stroke-width="100" />
```

It works, but for me it's the ugly solution. How can I do it better?

[image: Parts of circumference]

Comment: Because one part of circumference requires drawing two paths. I wonder if it is possible to draw one path instead of covering colourful fragment by white section. And if it will be better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function is called `describeArc()`, but is actually drawing a circular sector, not an arc.

I agree it is kind of ugly because you are unnecessarily drawing - and overdrawing - most of the sector.  And you will get issues with some of the colours bleeding around the edge of the white.  I assume that's why you are including the white stroke.

The solution is very simple.  Change the `describeArc()` function so that it is only drawing the arc, and not the rest of the sector.  Change the code as follows:

```
var d = [
    "M", start.x, start.y, 
    "A", radius, radius, 0, arcSweep, 0, end.x, end.y
].join(" ");
```

Ie. remove the two "L" path commands that form the other two sides of the sector.  In other words, use the answer by @opsb, not the @Ahtenus answer.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but when I was already tried using this version of `describeArc()` method, I set "stroke" and "fill" attributes conversely.