# Ellipse drawing By using arc in d3

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg, jquery-svg

I want to draw a ellipse by using arc. I did it for circle but i could not make it for ellipse.
Please help me for ellipse

**Code For Circle**

```js
var π = Math.PI,
    τ = 2 * π,
    n = 500;

var width = 300,
    height = 200,
    outerRadius = width / 2 - 20,
    innerRadius = outerRadius - 20;

d3.select("svg").append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + 200  + ")")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(d3.range(0, τ, τ / n))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(outerRadius)
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .startAngle(function(d) { return d; })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return d + τ / n * 1.1; }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`<ellipse>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/ellipse)?

Comment: I need to add ellipse by using arc in path element. this is my requirement

Comment: Fair enough! [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5737245/4235784) might help.

Comment: Sorry but it is adding ellipse with different path element, please check my above example where circle having different path element.  so that i can add different colors on each of the different element. I have to achieve rainbow ellipse

Answer (score 2):

The D3 `arc()` function only generates a circular arc segment.  It actually generates the outline of a solid shape based on the inner and outer radii you provide.

The only way you can transform that circular arc into an elliptical one is to scale the horizontal and vertical dimensions differently.  See below.

```js
var π = Math.PI,
    τ = 2 * π,
    n = 500;

var width = 300,
    height = 200,
    outerRadius = 1,
    innerRadius = 0.85,
    cx = 200,
    cy = 150;

d3.select("svg").append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cx + "," + cy + ") scale(" + (width/2) + "," + (height/2) + ")")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(d3.range(0, τ, τ / n))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(outerRadius)
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .startAngle(function(d) { return d; })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return d + τ / n * 1.1; }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
```

The drawback of course is that the uneven scaling messes with the thickness of the arc.  Maybe that's okay for you.  If not, you should maybe expand your question with further details of what you actually are trying to achieve.