# How to create an arc using JavaScript some maths and SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to do a function in order to get and arc on a SVG path.

I created a function named `drawArcSegment` which takes 4 params `startPercentage, endPercentage, radius, thickness`, and I have some pseudo code done

this is what I have already but I don't have an idea of how to ahead

```
var drawArcSegment = function(startPercentage, endPercentage, radius, thickness) {
  point1 = (R*cos(A), R*sin(A));
  point2 = ( (R-D)*cos(A), (R-D)*sin(A) );
  point3 = ( (R-D)*cos(B), (R-D)*sin(B) );
  point4 = (R*cos(B), R*sin(B));

  d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10";

  $("#myPath").attr("d", d);
}
```

the html part

```
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path stroke="black"
        stroke-dasharray="5,5"
        fill="green"
        id="myPath" />
</svg>
```

with the value of the `d` var, I get a square now. But I need something like this:
[image]

I have this [Pen](http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/PNXyxZ?editors=1010) in case you want to take a look.

So, any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle