# Shading inside an arc D3

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am working on an SVG, and came across the issue of trying to share different colors on separate sides of an arc. I have created this example to help go through this problem I'm having:

```js
const svg = d3.select('#chart') 
  .attr("viewBox", "0, 0, " + 50 + ", " + 47 + "")

// clip to cut off circle
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "cut-off")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 44)
  .attr("height", 23.75)
  .attr("x", 25)
  .attr("y", 42.25)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + -22 + "," + -28.5 + ")");

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 25)
  .attr("cy", 4.75)
  .attr("r", 23.75)
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("opacity", 0.25)
  .attr("stroke", 'black')
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.25)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#cut-off)");   
  
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 3)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 44)
  .attr("height", 14)
  .attr("fill", 'blue')
  .attr("opacity", 0.2)

// here's the one
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 14)
  .attr("width", 17)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", 'green')
  .attr("opacity", 0.2)
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 500px;
  height: 470px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg 
  version="1.1" 
  baseProfile="full"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     id="chart"></svg>
```

The rectangle that is currently shaded green I would like to instead shade two different colors. I would like the area inside of the arc (the area currently overlapping orange and green) to be set to one color, and the area outside of the arc (only green) to be set to another color. I think this probably requires using 2 rects, and cutting off the rects based on the circle, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Note: The way the arc was drawn was by drawing a circle, and then clipping a rectangle over the parts of the circle I don't want shown. Given that I'm trying to fill color differently based on what side of the circle's line the fill color is on, I'm not sure if this is the best way to draw the arc.

Thanks in advance for help with this!!

Comment: can you provide us with sample picture you want to achieve?

Comment: my code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cloneNode** on your green rect and set an [**clip-path**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) attribute on the clonedNode. Point the **clip-path** url to a circle with the same **d** attribute as your original circle defined under **defs** tag.

If you provide a fiddle, I can perhaps help.

Answer (score 0):

I used this link here - [How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle) - to solve the problem. Anybody trying to draw circles (or parts of a circle) as a path using svg arc should check this link.