# How to create a circle progress inside a Vue component

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, vue.js

I'm creating a component in my application built with Vue. This componet is a countdown, ranging from `X` minutes to `00:00`.

I know it's possible to animate `svg` to achieve the desired result, but I do not have the necessary knowledge. I have never used any `svg` library.

I need to create the following animation in my progress component:

[image: Progress bar animation sprites]

The animation need to follow the path according to the weather in a smooth way. The path nodes should be inserted / updated based on time.

This is my actual countdown component:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: moment(2 * 60 * 1000)
  },
  computed: {
    time: function(){
      return this.date.format('mm:ss');
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
   var timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.date = moment(this.date.subtract(1, 'seconds'));
        
      if(this.date.diff(moment(0)) === 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
        
        alert('Done!');
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{ time }}</div>
```

This is the svg for the progress circle:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
        .st1{fill:none;stroke:#B5B5B5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        .st2{fill:none;stroke:#408EFF;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
        .st3{fill:#408EFF;}
    </style>
    <rect class="st0" width="90" height="90"/>
    <circle class="st1" cx="45" cy="45" r="40"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M45,5c22.1,0,40,17.9,40,40S67.1,85,45,85S5,67.1,5,45S22.9,5,45,5"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="45" cy="5" r="3"/>
</svg>
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

All help would be welcome.

Comment: @Sphinx `setInterval` is required because my progress circle works with time instead of percentage. In addition, the animation is not perfect, besides not having the little circle at the end of the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to familiarize yourself with SVG shapes, in particular [`<path>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) in order to make the arc.

Here's an example:

```js
Vue.component('progress-ring', {
  template: '#progress-ring',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    min: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    max: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    },
    text: {
      type: null,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  computed: {
    theta() {
      const frac = (this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min) || 0;
      return frac * 2 * Math.PI;
    },
    path() {
      const large = this.theta > Math.PI;
      return `M0,-46 A46,46,0,${large ? 1 : 0},1,${this.endX},${this.endY}`;
    },
    endX() {
      return Math.cos(this.theta - Math.PI * 0.5) * 46;
    },
    endY() {
      return Math.sin(this.theta - Math.PI * 0.5) * 46;
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.progress-ring {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.progress-ring-circle {
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: none;
}

.progress-ring-ring {
  stroke: #007fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.progress-ring-end {
  fill: #007fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vuejs/vue/dev/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <progress-ring :min="0" :max="100" :value="40" text="12:34"></progress-ring>
</div>

<template id="progress-ring">
  <svg class="progress-ring" viewBox="-50,-50,100,100">
    <circle class="progress-ring-circle" r="46"/>
    <path class="progress-ring-ring" :d="path"/>
    <circle class="progress-ring-end" :cx="endX" :cy="endY" r="4"/>
    <text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">{{ text }}</text>
  </svg>
</template>
```

As for animating it, you just need to use JavaScript to change the `value` prop by using, for example, [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or some other means.

Answer (score 1):

Follow your template, one solution is pre-define the path into one array (each path node is one element of the array). Then push the path node to current progress path for each interval.

Like below demo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: moment(2 * 60 * 1000),
    pathRoute: ['M45 5', 'c22.1 0 40 17.9 40 40','S67.1 85 45 85','S5 67.1 5 45','S22.9 5 45 5'],
    pathProgess: [],
    stepIndex: 0
  },
  computed: {
    time: function(){
      return this.date.format('mm:ss');
    },
    computedProgress: function () {
      return this.pathProgess.join(' ')
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
   var timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.date = moment(this.date.subtract(1, 'seconds'));
      this.$set(this.pathProgess, this.stepIndex, this.pathRoute[this.stepIndex])
      this.stepIndex++
      if(this.date.diff(moment(0)) === 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
.st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
.st1{fill:none;stroke:#B5B5B5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.st2{fill:none;stroke:#408EFF;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.st3{fill:#408EFF;}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<p>{{computedProgress}}</p>
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
    <rect class="st0" width="90" height="90"/>
    <circle class="st1" cx="45" cy="45" r="40"/>
    <text class="circle-chart-percent" x="20.91549431" y="40.5" font-size="8">{{time}}</text>
    <path class="st2" :d="computedProgress"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="45" cy="5" r="3"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

Or you can use the approach [Answered at another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473154/5665870), to real time calculate the path.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    date: moment(2 * 60 * 1000),
    pathProgess: ''
  },
  computed: {
    time: function(){
      return this.date.format('mm:ss');
    }
  },
  mounted: function(){
    let maxValue = this.date.diff(moment(0), 'seconds') //total seconds
   var timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.date = moment(this.date.subtract(1, 'seconds'))
      let curValue = this.date.diff(moment(0), 'seconds') // current seconds
      this.pathProgess = this.describeArc(45, 45, 40, 0, (maxValue-curValue)*360/maxValue)
      if(this.date.diff(moment(0)) === 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 1000);
  },
  methods: {
      //copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473154/5665870
      polarToCartesian: function (centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
        var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

        return {
          x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
          y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
        };
      },
      //copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473154/5665870
      describeArc: function (x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

          var start = this.polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
          var end = this.polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

          var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

          var d = [
              "M", start.x, start.y, 
              "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
          ].join(" ");

          return d;       
      }
  }
});
```

```css
.st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
.st1{fill:none;stroke:#B5B5B5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.st2{fill:none;stroke:#408EFF;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.st3{fill:#408EFF;}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<p>{{pathProgess}}</p>
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
    <rect class="st0" width="90" height="90"/>
    <circle class="st1" cx="45" cy="45" r="40"/>
    <text class="circle-chart-percent" x="20.91549431" y="40.5" font-size="8">{{time}}</text>
    <path class="st2" :d="pathProgess"/>
    <circle class="st3" cx="45" cy="5" r="3"/>
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Cool, but the circle should be closed gradually, accompanied by the time returned from `setInterval`.

Comment: Is it possible to the circle and the blue stroke follow the path parallel to the total time? 0% = 2:00, 100% = 00:00. The transition should be smooth.

Comment: The path nodes should be inserted/updated based on time

Comment: @CaioKawasaki check the second demo, it will be what you need.