# Calculating SVG arc path on circle

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

i am trying to draw a SVG objects similar to pie chart using the SVG path element. I had earlier used the example from this  [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle) to generate the SVG arc path. But somehow my two arc which are supposed be part of same circle dont form a full circle. here is the code example i used to generate my arcs on a circle.

```js
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 130)

var radi = 20;
var st = {'x':0,'y':0};

var pie1Arc = this.describeArc(this.st.x,this.st.y,this.radi,0,42) 
var pie1 = draw.path('M 0 0 '+ pie1Arc)
pie1.fill('none')
pie1.stroke({ color: '#f06', width: 3, linecap: 'round', linejoin: 'round' })
pie1.move(80,80)


var pie2Arc = this.describeArc(this.st.x,this.st.y,this.radi,42,360) 
var pie2 = draw.path('M 0 0 '+ pie2Arc)
pie2.fill('none')
pie2.stroke({ color: '#f06', width: 3, linecap: 'round', linejoin: 'round' })
pie2.move(80,80)

    
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

    var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

    var d = [
        "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
    ].join(" ");

    return d;       
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.5.0/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've rewritten the `describeArc` and also reset the `st = {'x':80,'y':80};` instead of moving each arc. If you really need to translate put the 2 arcs in a group and translate the group.

```js
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 130)

var radi = 20;
var st = {'x':80,'y':80};

var pie1Arc = this.describeArc(this.st.x,this.st.y,this.radi,0,42) 
var pie1 = draw.path(pie1Arc)
pie1.fill('none')
pie1.stroke({ color: '#f06', width: 3, linecap: 'round', linejoin: 'round' })



var pie2Arc = this.describeArc(this.st.x,this.st.y,this.radi,42,360) 
var pie2 = draw.path(pie2Arc)
pie2.fill('none')
pie2.stroke({ color: '#f06', width: 3, linecap: 'round', linejoin: 'round' })


    
function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees-90) * Math.PI / 180.0;

  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){

    var start = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
    var end = polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);

    var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";

    var d = `M${start.x},${start.y}A${radius}, ${radius}, 0, ${largeArcFlag}, 0, ${end.x}, ${end.y}`;
    

    return d;       
}
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.5.0/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing"></div>
```