# SVG continuous inwards square spiral animation with pure CSS/JS

Tags: css, animation, svg, polyline

I need some help with this kinda specific animation. It is a square spiral pattern that keeps going inwards until it's fully complete. I somewhat did manage to get it going but I don't know how to stop the animation properly, and I'm not sure if the math behind it is mostly efficient/correct.

Here's what I have for now:

```js
function createSquareSpiralPath(
  strokeWidth,
  width,
  height,
) {
  const maxIterations = Math.trunc(Math.min(width, height) / 2 / strokeWidth); // ???
  let path = '';
  for (let i = 0; i <= maxIterations; i++) {
    const step = strokeWidth * i;
    const computed = [
      `${step},${height - step}`,
      `${step},${step}`,
      `${width - step - strokeWidth},${step}`,
      `${width - step - strokeWidth},${height - step - strokeWidth} `,
    ];
    path += computed.join(' ');
  }

  return path.trim();
}
```

```css
.spiral {
  stroke-dasharray: 6130;
  stroke-dashoffset: 6130;
  animation: moveToTheEnd 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes moveToTheEnd {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 350 350" height="350" width="350">
  <polyline class="spiral" points="
  0,350 0,0 330,0 330,330 20,330 20,20 310,20 310,310 40,310 40,40 290,40 290,290 60,290 60,60 270,60 270,270 80,270 80,80 250,80 250,250 100,250 100,100 230,100 230,230 120,230 120,120 210,120 210,210 140,210 140,140 190,140 190,190 160,190 160,160 170,160 170,170"
  style="fill:transparent;stroke:black;stroke-width:20" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

I added the js function just to demonstrate how I'm generating the points. As you can see the animation plays exactly how I want, I just can't find a way to wrap it up properly. Also, I'm unsure if this function would generate correct points for varying width/height/strokeWidth.

I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance. :)

PS.: I could not find a mathematical term for this pattern (square-ish spiral) so I'm more than happy to learn how to call it properly.

**Edit**

Based on @enxaneta answers (thank you!) it seems I'm incorrectly calculating the max number of iterations. This can be seen whenever `width !== height`. I'll do some research on how I'm producing this value, maybe this formula isn't adequate to properly "stop" the animation without any blank space.

Comment: Nice. If your goal is to fill the whole square you can use `stroke-linecap: square` for the polyline, making shure the `points` start 20 units above the present starting point. In this case at 0,330 instead of 0,350 (20 is the stroke width). And you can also use setAttribute to set the calculated points attribute of the polyline

Comment: It worked for several tests, but still won't cover 100%. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hgrduwx7/1/ Although it's unlike that I'll be using this thin, I wanted to know if there's anything else I could do? Also, thank you very much for lending me your time!

Comment: Apparently you are looping too many times. (3 extra iterations). If you remove the extra iterations you close the gap. Please take a look at the way you are calculating the maxIterations and also at the for loop (<= ?)

Comment: I'll do some research on that, @enxaneta. Square values (width equals height) are mostly fine, but it's giving me all sorts of different results for various strokeWidth and whenever width !== height. I'll try to get to some consistent max number of iterations. Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to say gorgeous animation! Would love to see more of these complex visual SVG stuff on SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you also need to check if your current drawing position has already reached a maximum x/y (close to you center).

The calculation for the loops iterations works fine.
Currently you're drawing 4 new points in each step.

Depending on your `stroke-width` you might need to stop drawing e.g after the 2. or 3. point when you're close to the center X/Y coordinates.

```js
let spiral1 = createSquareSpiralPath(50, 500, 1000);
let spiral1_2 = createSquareSpiralPath(20, 1000, 500);
let spiral2 = createSquareSpiralPath(150, 300, 300);


function createSquareSpiralPath(strokeWidth, width, height) {
  let maxIterations = Math.trunc(Math.min(width, height) / 2 / strokeWidth); 
  let coords = [];

  //calculate max X/Y coordinates according to stroke-width 
  let strokeToWidthRatio = width * 1 / strokeWidth;
  let strokeToHeightRatio = height * 1 / strokeWidth;
  let maxX = (width - strokeWidth / strokeToWidthRatio) / 2;
  let maxY = (height - strokeWidth / strokeToHeightRatio) / 2;

  for (let i = 0; i <= maxIterations; i++) {
    const step = strokeWidth * i;
    // calculate points in iteration    
    let [x1, y1] = [step, (height - step)];
    let [x2, y2] = [step, step];
    let [x3, y3] = [(width - step - strokeWidth), step];
    let [x4, y4] = [(width - step - strokeWidth), (height - step - strokeWidth)];

    //stop drawing if max X/Y coordinates are reached 
    if (x1 <= maxX && y1 >= maxY) {
      coords.push(x1, y1)
    }
    if (x2 <= maxX && y2 <= maxY) {
      coords.push(x2, y2)
    }
    if (x3 >= maxX && y3 <= maxY) {
      coords.push(x3, y3)
    }
    if (x4 >= maxX && y4 >= maxY) {
      coords.push(x4, y4)
    }
  }
  let points = coords.join(' ');

  //calc pathLength from coordinates
  let pathLength = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < coords.length - 2; i += 2) {
    let x1 = coords[i];
    let y1 = coords[i + 1];
    let x2 = coords[i + 2];
    let y2 = coords[i + 3];
    let length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    pathLength += length;
  }

  //optional: render svg
  renderSpiralSVG(points, pathLength, width, height, strokeWidth);
  return [points, pathLength];
}


function renderSpiralSVG(points, pathLength, width, height, strokeWidth) {
  const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  let svgTmp = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
  svgTmp.setAttribute(
    "viewBox", [-strokeWidth / 2, -strokeWidth / 2, width, height].join(" ")
  );
  let newPolyline = document.createElementNS(ns, "polyline");
  newPolyline.classList.add("spiral");
  newPolyline.setAttribute("points", points);
  svgTmp.appendChild(newPolyline);
  document.body.appendChild(svgTmp);

  newPolyline.setAttribute(
    "style",
    `fill:transparent;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-linecap: square;
    stroke-width:${strokeWidth}; 
    stroke-dashoffset: ${pathLength};
    stroke-dasharray: ${pathLength};`
  );
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20vw;
}

.spiral {
  stroke-width: 1;
  animation: moveToTheEnd 1s linear forwards;
}

.spiral:hover {
  stroke-width: 1!important;
}

@keyframes moveToTheEnd {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Hover to see spiral lines</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed thought process, you really unraveled the inner working of my function and found the issue. I was starting to stir towards that same realization, but you shortened the path a lot! I appreciate you taking the time to read through my question and assisting me, thank you so much. (Plus, the hover thing cleared my mind a ton!)

Answer (score 3):

To control the animation, instead of CSS, use the Web Animations API

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API
- Wrap all in a standard Web Component (JSWC) `<svg-spiral>` with shadowDOM, so you can have multiple components on screen without any global CSS  conflicts.
- set a `pathLenght="100"` on the polygon, so you don't have to do calculations
- `stroke-dasharray` must be written as: `strokeDasharray` in WAAPI
- The animation triggers an `onfinish` **function**
- clicking an `<svg-spiral>` in the SO snippet below will restart the animation

```html
<div style="display:grid;grid:1fr/repeat(4,1fr)">
  <svg-spiral></svg-spiral>
  <svg-spiral stroke="rebeccapurple" width="1000" strokewidth="10"></svg-spiral>
  <svg-spiral stroke="blue" duration="10000"></svg-spiral>
  <svg-spiral stroke="red" width="6000" duration="1e4"></svg-spiral>
</div>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-spiral", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let strokewidth = this.getAttribute("strokewidth") || 30;
      let width = this.getAttribute("width") || 500; let height = this.getAttribute("height") || width;
      let points = '';
      for (let i = 0; i <= ~~(Math.min(width, height) / 2 / strokewidth); i++) {
        const step = strokewidth * i;
        points += `${step},${height - step} ${step},${step} ${width - step - strokewidth},${step} ${width - step - strokewidth},${height - step - strokewidth}  `;
      }
      this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="-${strokewidth/2}-${strokewidth/2} ${width} ${height}"><polyline class="spiral" pathLength="100" points="${points}z"
            fill="transparent" stroke-width="${strokewidth}" /></svg>`;
      this.onclick = (e) => this.animate();
      this.animate();
    }
    animate() {
      let spiral = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".spiral");
      spiral.setAttribute("stroke", this.getAttribute("stroke") || "black");
      let player = spiral.animate(
        [{ strokeDashoffset: 100, strokeDasharray: 100, opacity: 0 }, 
         { strokeDashoffset: 0,   strokeDasharray: 100, opacity: 1 }], 
         {
          duration: ~~(this.getAttribute("duration") || 5000),
          iterations: 1
        });
      player.onfinish = (e) => { spiral.setAttribute("stroke", "green") }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that I found out the tool I'm using (react-native-svg) does not offer support for these APIs, mainly `pathLength`, which is the super cool solution. I have to stick to dash array and dash offset. Biggest problem is the tiny blank space at the end.

Comment: Lucky you, had you tagged your question ``React`` I wouldn't have answered

Comment: I'm sorry about that. The fundamentals are mostly the same, but there are some limitations which make the solution a bit constrained. Thank you for pitching in nonetheless, I really appreciate your kindness.