# Trying to do a very simple clip/mask in SVG.JS

Tags: svg, svg.js

I have a white inner circle and a blue outer circle.

I am trying to clip out the white inner circle to leave a blue ring.

(I know I can achieve the same thing using a single circle and a stroke, but I will be using more complex shapes in the future and want to achieve this simple task first.)

[image]

I have tried variations of the following:

```
const container = SVG().addTo('body').size(500, 500)

const bg = container.rect(500,500).fill('green')

// outer circle
const outerCircle = container.circle(100).fill('blue');

// inner circle
const innerCircle = container.circle(80).fill('white').center(outerCircle.cx(), outerCircle.cy());

// Clip the outer circle with the inner circle
outerCircle.clipWith(innerCircle);
```

However, this removes the outer circle, like so:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's a public JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j1pq7drb/

Comment: Clip paths works the other way round: they will only show the area within its the clip path shape. You could use a [mask instead](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ExOWEXr)

Comment: Should the area/white circle be transparent so that you can see the white color behind the green? OR is it fine that the green color shows?

Comment: I want the green be visible. herrstrietzel's fiddle is exactly what I want to acheive, but I want to use SVG.JS if possible rather than raw SVG. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you know you can use a `mask` instead of clip to achieve the desired affect.

In SVG.JS, you can use [`maskWith`](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/shape-elements/#maskwith), which will look something like this:

```
const container = SVG().addTo('body').size(500, 500);

const bg = container.rect(500,500).fill('green');

// outer circle
const outerCircle = container.circle(100).fill('blue');
const maskGroup = container.mask();

// This is to allow the original shape to be visible. Could also be done with a clone of the original shape
maskGroup.rect(500,500).fill('white');

// Add the inner circle to the group
maskGroup.circle(80).fill('black').center(outerCircle.cx(), outerCircle.cy());

// Mask the outer circle with the the group
outerCircle.maskWith(maskGroup);
```

Since `Mask` inherits from `SVG.Container` in SVG.JS, you can be very creative with its usage. For more complicated shapes (multiple polkadots, as an example), you can create groups inside your mask to keep everything tidy.

```
const container = SVG().addTo('body').size(500, 500);
const bg = container.rect(500,500).fill('green');

// Create some shape
const shape = container.circle(250).center(200, 200).fill('pink');

// Create the mask def
const mask = container.mask();

// Add a white rectangle the size of the svg to allow the shapes to be visible
mask.rect(500, 500).fill('white');

// Create a group within the mask
const polkaDots = mask.group();

// Add circles to the mask which will appear "cut out" of the main shape
polkaDots.circle(20).center(250, 210).fill('black');
polkaDots.circle(50).center(150, 200).fill('black');
polkaDots.circle(30).center(200, 120).fill('black');

// Apply the mask to the shape
shape.maskWith(mask);
```

This has an added benefit of allowing you to use group styles or group positioning to make sweeping changes.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've recommended `<mask>` as a workaround ...

### `<mask>` vs. `<clipPath>` – don't forget compound paths

Sure compound paths require a better understanding of SVG path commands, but it's worthwhile!

Actually, each "e" and "o" you see in this post – rendered from text, based on a font etc. – relies on compound paths – a path containing an outer and inner shapes that appear "cut out" (like the letter O).

For simple tasks like rendering a "donut" shape, you should prefer compound paths over masks or clip paths.

```js
const container = SVG().addTo('body').size(500, 500)
const bg = container.rect(500,500).fill('green')

let donutPathData = createDonutPathData(20, 30, 100, 80);
const donut = container.path(donutPathData).fill('blue');

// create donut paths
function createDonutPathData(x, y, d1, d2){
  let strokeWidth = (d1-d2)
  let pathData = 
      // outer circle
      createCirclePathData(x, y, d1, 1) + 
      // inner circle (cut out)
      ' '+ createCirclePathData(0, strokeWidth/2, d2, 0, true)
  return pathData;
}

// create circle paths
function createCirclePathData(x=0, y=0, d=100, sweep=1, relative=false ){
  let M = relative ? `m ${x} ${y}` : `M ${d/2+x} ${y}`;
  let pathData = `${M} a ${d/2} ${d/2} 0 0 ${sweep} 0 ${d} a ${d/2} ${d/2} 0 0 ${sweep} 0 -${d}`;
  return pathData;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/3.2.0/svg.min.js"></script>
```

#### How it works

We're using a custom helper function `createCirclePathData()` generating arcs according to radius and x/y values returning a `d` pathData attribute string which can be passed to SVG.js `path()` method.

A donut shape could easily be created with one path including a subpath like so – outer diameter=100; inner diameter=80:

```
M 50 0
A 50 50 0 0 1 50 100
A 50 50 0 0 1 50 0
M 50 10
A 40 40 0 0 0 50 90
A 40 40 0 0 0 50 10
```

Both outer and inner circle are based on the [`A` (Arc) command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#arcs)

The above code translates to

```
/**
* starting point: x = r or diameter/2; 
*/
M 50 0 
/**
* outer circle: 
* radius, radius, angle, long arc flag, sweep flag (clockwise or counterclockwise), final x, final y 
*/
A 50 50 0 0 1 50 100
A 50 50 0 0 1 50 0

/** inner circle: 
* new starting point according to inner diameter
* radius and final points change accordingly – 
* we change the path direction via sweep flag. 
* This way the inner circle will define the cut-out shape
*/ 
M 50 10
A 40 40 0 0 0 50 90
A 40 40 0 0 0 50 10
```

See also ["How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle/) (and a lot more posts tackling pie charts in svg)

The additional custom function `createDonutPathData()` is just a wrapper to generate a path `d` value with outer and inner circle pathData.

The benefits of this approach:

- no need for additional `fill-rule` attributes (that might not be supported by all applications
- more compact output – no need for `<clipPath>` or `<mask>` definitions
- no need for legacy syntax references like `xlink:href` – still required by a lot of graphic applications or image viewers.

### Benefits of `<mask>`

- masks are great for complex shapes like dashed strokes
- support semi-transparency

### Caveats of `<mask>`

- more expensive because they introduce an alpha transparency rendering context
- The pointer area is not "clipped" to the visible shape: A masked element responds to pointer events in the same way as the original/unmasked element, even in transparent/masked areas.