# How to make a textPath but for image not path in svg

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I'm doing pretty simple svg rendering, like

```
<svg>
  <image href="rounded_image.svg" width="35" height="35" />
</svg>
```

where rounded image looks like this

```html
<svg width="652" height="652" viewBox="0 0 652 652" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g filter="url(#filter0_ddiii_724_876)"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M296 390C347.915 390 390 347.915 390 296C390 244.085 347.915 202 296 202C244.085 202 202 244.085 202 296C202 347.915 244.085 390 296 390ZM296 590C458.372 590 590 458.372 590 296C590 133.628 458.372 2 296 2C133.628 2 2 133.628 2 296C2 458.372 133.628 590 296 590Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_724_876)"/><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M296 390C347.915 390 390 347.915 390 296C390 244.085 347.915 202 296 202C244.085 202 202 244.085 202 296C202 347.915 244.085 390 296 390ZM296 590C458.372 590 590 458.372 590 296C590 133.628 458.372 2 296 2C133.628 2 2 133.628 2 296C2 458.372 133.628 590 296 590Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear_724_876)" fill-opacity="0.5" style="mix-blend-mode:overlay"/></g><defs><filter id="filter0_ddiii_724_876" x="-30" y="-30" width="682" height="682" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/><feOffset dx="10" dy="10"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/><feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.21 0"/><feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_724_876"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/><feOffset dx="30" dy="30"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="16"/><feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0125 0 0 0 0 0.00641447 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.3 0"/><feBlend mode="normal" in2="effect1_dropShadow_724_876" result="effect2_dropShadow_724_876"/><feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect2_dropShadow_724_876" result="shape"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/><feOffset dx="-25" dy="-25"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="47"/><feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.554735 0 0 0 0 0.232989 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.58 0"/><feBlend mode="normal" in2="shape" result="effect3_innerShadow_724_876"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/><feOffset/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12.5"/><feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.4 0"/><feBlend mode="overlay" in2="effect3_innerShadow_724_876" result="effect4_innerShadow_724_876"/><feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/><feOffset dx="-40" dy="-40"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="16"/><feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.15 0"/><feBlend mode="overlay" in2="effect4_innerShadow_724_876" result="effect5_innerShadow_724_876"/></filter><radialGradient id="paint0_radial_724_876" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(296 296) rotate(-60.3555) scale(283.048 283.048)"><stop stop-color="#FFD481"/><stop offset="0.617362" stop-color="#FFDB8E"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCD48C"/></radialGradient><linearGradient id="paint1_linear_724_876" x1="500.5" y1="547" x2="57" y2="51.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop/><stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/></linearGradient></defs></svg>
```

So I want to add a curved text to the bottom of this image to make it looking like this

[image]

Text should be curved and placed on the bottom of image. I've tried to do this using textPath, like this:

```
<svg>
  <image id="dough" href="rounded_image.svg" width="35" height="35" />
  <text>
    <textPath href="#dough">
      My custom text
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

But obviously no luck displaying text, at all.
I'd like to see good implementation, js answers are acceptable too - I'm using React to render svg component

Comment: Since you are using an image you will need to add a path to the svg element (in the defs) to be used as textPath

Comment: You need to create a single circular `<path>`  element. `textPath` can't  align to complete svg files. But you can easily create an appripriate path according to the `<image>` elements width/height. See also ["How to calculate the SVG Path for an arc (of a circle)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736398/how-to-calculate-the-svg-path-for-an-arc-of-a-circle/76710168#76710168)

Comment: It's only because your text should say "My Delicious Glazed Donut!"  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert at `SVG`s, but here's my solution (Stackoverflow doesn't seem to display it correctly for some reason):

```css
svg {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="652" height="652" viewBox="0 0 652 652" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_ddiii_724_876)">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M296 390C347.915 390 390 347.915 390 296C390 244.085 347.915 202 296 202C244.085 202 202 244.085 202 296C202 347.915 244.085 390 296 390ZM296 590C458.372 590 590 458.372 590 296C590 133.628 458.372 2 296 2C133.628 2 2 133.628 2 296C2 458.372 133.628 590 296 590Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_724_876)"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M296 390C347.915 390 390 347.915 390 296C390 244.085 347.915 202 296 202C244.085 202 202 244.085 202 296C202 347.915 244.085 390 296 390ZM296 590C458.372 590 590 458.372 590 296C590 133.628 458.372 2 296 2C133.628 2 2 133.628 2 296C2 458.372 133.628 590 296 590Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear_724_876)" fill-opacity="0.5" style="mix-blend-mode:overlay"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
      <filter id="filter0_ddiii_724_876" x="-30" y="-30" width="682" height="682" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
        <feOffset dx="10" dy="10"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
        <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.21 0"/>
        <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_724_876"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
        <feOffset dx="30" dy="30"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="16"/>
        <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0125 0 0 0 0 0.00641447 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.3 0"/>
        <feBlend mode="normal" in2="effect1_dropShadow_724_876" result="effect2_dropShadow_724_876"/>
        <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect2_dropShadow_724_876" result="shape"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
        <feOffset dx="-25" dy="-25"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="47"/>
        <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.554735 0 0 0 0 0.232989 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.58 0"/>
        <feBlend mode="normal" in2="shape" result="effect3_innerShadow_724_876"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
        <feOffset/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12.5"/>
        <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.4 0"/>
        <feBlend mode="overlay" in2="effect3_innerShadow_724_876" result="effect4_innerShadow_724_876"/>
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
        <feOffset dx="-40" dy="-40"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="16"/>
        <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.15 0"/>
        <feBlend mode="overlay" in2="effect4_innerShadow_724_876" result="effect5_innerShadow_724_876"/>
      </filter>
      <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_724_876" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(296 296) rotate(-60.3555) scale(283.048 283.048)">
        <stop stop-color="#FFD481"/>
        <stop offset="0.617362" stop-color="#FFDB8E"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCD48C"/>
      </radialGradient>
      <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_724_876" x1="500.5" y1="547" x2="57" y2="51.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="customText" viewBox="0 0 800 652">
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none"
      d="M 157,295 a 295,295 0 0 0 590,0" />
  <text>
    <textPath startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" href="#MyPath">my custom text</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Most of it is your `SVG`, but at the bottom, I've just added this bit of code:

```html
<svg class="customText" viewBox="0 0 800 652">
  <path id="MyPath" fill="none"
      d="M 157,295 a 295,295 0 0 0 590,0" />
  <text>
    <textPath startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle" href="#MyPath">my custom text</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

and the CSS to format it!

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to come back later but here is a "partial fix" since the text is on the wrong side/direction and I don't have more time to update the text flow to fix this super fast update ATM sorry for that.

- Changed the SVG `fill="#00008B"` to have a color (I randomly choose a dark blue)
- Added the `<path id="textcircle" ...` with that id
- Added `<style> text {`  for the text size etc.
- Used that case sensitive ID: `<textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">`
- Note some updates are in `defs` and some outside of it.
- added the xlink namespace to the svg: `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

```html
<svg width="652" height="652" viewBox="0 0 652 652" fill="#00008B" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <g filter="url(#filter0_ddiii_724_876)">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M296 390C347.915 390 390 347.915 390 296C390 244.085 347.915 202 296 202C244.085 202 202 244.085 202 296C202 347.915 244.085 390 296 390ZM296 590C458.372 590 590 458.372 590 296C590 133.628 458.372 2 296 2C133.628 2 2 133.628 2 296C2 458.372 133.628 590 296 590Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial_724_876)"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M296 390C347.915 390 390 347.915 390 296C390 244.085 347.915 202 296 202C244.085 202 202 244.085 202 296C202 347.915 244.085 390 296 390ZM296 590C458.372 590 590 458.372 590 296C590 133.628 458.372 2 296 2C133.628 2 2 133.628 2 296C2 458.372 133.628 590 296 590Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear_724_876)" fill-opacity="0.5" style="mix-blend-mode:overlay"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_ddiii_724_876" x="-30" y="-30" width="682" height="682" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
            <feOffset dx="10" dy="10"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.21 0"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_724_876"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
            <feOffset dx="30" dy="30"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="16"/>
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.0125 0 0 0 0 0.00641447 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.3 0"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in2="effect1_dropShadow_724_876" result="effect2_dropShadow_724_876"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect2_dropShadow_724_876" result="shape"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
            <feOffset dx="-25" dy="-25"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="47"/>
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.554735 0 0 0 0 0.232989 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.58 0"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in2="shape" result="effect3_innerShadow_724_876"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
            <feOffset/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12.5"/>
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0.4 0"/>
            <feBlend mode="overlay" in2="effect3_innerShadow_724_876" result="effect4_innerShadow_724_876"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
            <feOffset dx="-40" dy="-40"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="16"/>
            <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.15 0"/>
            <feBlend mode="overlay" in2="effect4_innerShadow_724_876" result="effect5_innerShadow_724_876"/>
        </filter>
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_724_876" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(296 296) rotate(-60.3555) scale(283.048 283.048)">
            <stop stop-color="#FFD481"/>
            <stop offset="0.617362" stop-color="#FFDB8E"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FCD48C"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <linearGradient id="paint1_linear_724_876" x1="500.5" y1="547" x2="57" y2="51.5" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <path id="textcircle" d="M240.2, 382.4c-74.8, 0-135.5-60.7-135.5-135.5s60.7-135.5,135.5-135.5s135.5, 60.7, 135.5, 135.5 S318, 382.4, 243.2, 382.4z"
        transform="rotate(90 250 300)" />
         <style>
            text { 
                font-size: 32px;
                font-family: Franklin Gothic, sans-serif;
                font-weight: 900; 
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: 10px;
                z-index: -100;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    
    <text dy="-100" textLength="500">
        <textPath xlink:href="#textcircle">
            Delicious Glazed Donut
        </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```